# How to create a folder in Visual Studio C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, project, directory

I have started my first bigger project with Visual Studio 2012 in C++. I will structure my Source-files in folders, but I can not find where I can create real folders, like in the windows explorer. So here is my question.

How can I create real folders in my project?

Comment: You can right click the project to have the option of opening the folder, if it's any consolation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The IDE has a command for that, "New Folder".  It is even present in the Project + Add context menu, something you can see when you look at the context menu with Tools + Customize.  It is however hidden in the C++ IDE.  Intentionally.

Its important to understand why it is hidden.  It keeps you out of trouble, the kind of trouble you'll get into when you create folders with Explorer.

At issue is the way C++ files get built.  They produce an .obj file when the compiler is done with them.  That obj file is stored in a directory whose name is a project setting.  You see it with Project + Properties, General, Intermediate Directory setting.  For an individual .cpp file, it is C/C++, Output Files, Object File Name.  The default for that one is `$(IntDir)` a macro that tells the compiler to use the Intermediate Directory setting.  With the default settings, all .obj files for the Debug build end up in the Debug subdirectory.  Release subdirectory for the Release build.  Regardless where the .cpp was stored.

Maybe you see the bear trap by now.  If you create a subdirectory with .cpp files then you'll get in trouble when that subdirectory has a .cpp file whose name is identical to another .cpp file in another subdirectory.  They produce an .obj file with the same name.  One overwrites the other, which ever one was compiled last.  That produces **very** mystifying linker errors.  You'll get duplicate symbol errors because the last built .obj file is linked twice and missing symbol errors for the overwritten .obj file.

So go ahead and create a subdirectory but beware this problem.  You have to change the Object File Name setting for the .cpp file if such a collision happens.

Comment: Thanks, for your detailed description but in this moment I am deinstalling VS2012 and download the Qt-Creator again, an wonderful IDE from programmers for programmers. No need to install thousand addons for the minimal standard functions.

Comment: It's funny that a easy-to-solve shortcoming of the default build settings is masked by hiding the exact feature that would expose the flaw...

Comment: -1 Doesn't work (for me). I agree with @rubenvb, it's funny (in a tragical way) that that feature is hidden, to mask an easy to solve "problem". Be that is it may, there is apparently no way to activate (whatever the word) that menu item. I tried. So, what is the magic incantation?

Comment: +1 for being highly informative. Honesty cannot be downplayed IMO. Even if it ... sucks :)

Comment: @Alf: It's called "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer or something, and instead of virtual filters and whatnot, you get actual hard drive folders displayed.

Comment: Sigh, they do shoot the messenger around here.  Bitching at me about it is just utterly pointless.

Comment: @Hans: You should change your description to instead talk about "Show All Files" as DeadMG explains. I just tested, that works (it shows the "Add Folder" menu item). Then it would be an answer. ;-)

Comment: I documented a build problem you can get from creating folders and explained why the command is hidden by default and what you do about it if it blows up.  Clearly in an effort to be more helpful than everybody's "here's a gun, aim it at your foot" answers.  That you didn't think that was helpful, even worthy of a downvote, is surely a lack of imagination on your end.

Comment: @Hans: You should change your description to instead talk about "Show All Files" as DeadMG explains. I just tested, that works (it shows the "Add Folder" menu item). Then it would be an answer. ;-)

Comment: +1 Great explanation. Still, I'd rather get a build warning stating that an obj is being overwritten than have to jump through these hoops. Obj's should just be built with GUID-based names, anyway. Only the source-level identifiers should matter.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am working with F#, trying to create a physical folder where to stick markdown files with the user guide of my library. I don't get your explanation: *"The IDE has a command for that, "New Folder". It is even present in the Project + Add context menu, something you can see when you look at the context menu with Tools + Customize."* Thanks.

Comment: This is about the C++ IDE, you'll have to ask your own question.

Comment: This is a problem in Google's webp - there are two quant.c and now i am going crazy

Comment: I tried this solution, but it is not working for me, what I did is to add the files in the Source Code explorer, but the folder with files is not presented in the solution, at least I know that is secure in my source control (at least)

Answer (score 1):

This is mildly annoying, however, here is what can be done:

Create the new folder in Visual Studio. This does not create a new folder in the file system. Add a new item to the folder. Choose the proper directory for the item.

For example, if your project is at %Documents%\Project, and your new folder name is Folder, then you add a new item to that folder at %Documents%\Project\Folder.

Visual Studio 2012 will put the item in the folder where you want it. If you add a new item, it will default to the same folder. That is where the annoying part comes in. If you create 3 folders for all your project items and try to add a new item to each folder, Visual Studio will try to put all 3 items in the same place in the file system (the last folder you added a new item to), while putting items into the correct Visual Studio folder.

It is possible there is a setting for this in Visual Studio. I haven't found it. I also haven't looked that hard.